# kendo: How to exclude time part from OdataString

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using toOdataString method to convert filterExpression to OdataString. When field is of date Type, time is also getting included.

When user is selecting some date let say 08-april-2021 While converting to odataString it adds time part as well.

Units Date eq 2021-04-08T00:00:00.000Z

Stackblitz for reproduction : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dzo3tn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.ccomponent.ts

Note: check in console for the output

Can it be created like $filter=date(unitdate) eq 2021-04-08  ??

reference: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1473

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to remove the TimeZone part of the date. Please check the following code:

```
let queryStr = `${toODataString(state)}`;
const regex = /T00:00:00\.000Z/gi;
const noTimeZoneQueryStr = queryStr.replace(regex, '');
console.log("noTimeZoneQueryStr", noTimeZoneQueryStr);
```

Please find the updated Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w7m4kd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.ccomponent.ts

**Edit** regarding the note: Yes. Please consider the following code:

```
let queryStr = `${toODataString(state)}`;
const dateStr = /(r=| )Units Date /g;
let newQueryStr = queryStr.replace(dateStr, '$1date(Units Date) ');
const regex = /T00:00:00\.000Z/gi;
const noTimeZoneQueryStr = newQueryStr.replace(regex, '');
console.log("noTimeZoneQueryStr", noTimeZoneQueryStr);
```

Please find the updated Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jqma46?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.ccomponent.ts

Comment: Thank for the solution. You rock !!!!!!

Let me give it a try